# Creating a Count Method

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method where you can put in an array position (like a[b]) and it will count the total number of that element that there are. This is what I have come up with:

```
public static int getCount(double a[b])
    {
        int count;
        int Element;
        for(Element = 0; Element < a.length; Element++)
        {
            if(a[b] = a[Element])
            {
                return count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this will not compile. Why is that? And also, is this the most efficient way to get the total number of a certain element of an array?

Comment: the problem is with a[b]

Comment: you mean double [] not [b]

Comment: You mean the compiler did not tell you?

Comment: What I was trying to do was make a method that would allow you to type something like this: class.getCount(arrayname[0], and then it returns the total number of that element that there is. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the signature and the reference in the method:

```
// How many times is "d" in array "a"?
public static int getCount(double[] a, double d) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int e : a) {
        if(e == d) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

You may use a `DoubleStream` and return the casted result of `count` after having filtered the stream

```
public static int getCount(double[] a, double d) {
    return (int) DoubleStream.of(a)
                             .filter(x -> x == d)
                             .count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the array and array element's position as separate parameters to the function. Easiest solution would be to create an **extension method** which will take array & array position as parameters and return the count of element present at that position.

```
int[] a = new int[8]{1,2,3,4,5,3,6,3};
a.getCount(3);

static class Extension
{
    public static int GetCount(this Array arr, int position)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if(position < arr.Length)
        {
            var searchElement = arr.GetValue(position - 1);
            foreach(var element in arr)
            {
                if(searchElement.Equals(element))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Benefit here is that you can call this function for any type of Array.

Comment: Please add some code to explain what your answer